# Favicons still fetching despite caching them

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have a list of favicons

[image: list of favicons]

Am using a service worker to cache all files, i.e. its a PWA, my files are as below

```
"/",
"/index.html",
"/favicon/apple-touch-icon.png",
"/favicon/favicon-32x32.png",
"/favicon/favicon-16x16.png",
"/favicon/site.webmanifest",
"/favicon/safari-pinned-tab.svg",
"/favicon/favicon.ico",
"/favicon/browserconfig.xml",
"/app.css",
"/app.js",
```

The problem is with my two very specific files,

[image: files that won't cache]

These two files `/favicon/favicon-32x32.png` and `/favicon/favicon-16x16.png`. Any help here please would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: No I didn't, i eventually decided to let it go since they are small sized files so there won't be too much of a difference

Answer (score 11):

This is a known Chrome bug. It is known from 2016. No solution till now due to security issue.

[Chrome bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=448427#c16)

Update at 26-11-2018 solved

[Service worker: FetchEvents for requests for same-origin favicons](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6405336307073024)

Comment: There's either a regression or this was never completely fixed. New bug report: [Issue 969033: Favicons are being requested on page reload](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=969033&q=favicon&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot of network requests, I couldn't see how SW caching for all other requests are working. I could see one 304. That alone wont imply SW is working fine. If you can province a full networks tab screenshot(may be hiding files names?) it will help understand the problem better.

On general debugging to check service worker,

1) Make sure "service worker" under chrome dev tools -> Application is coming with your domain in green.

2) If its not green, you might be missing to configure SW correctly or build process is missing the required manifest files.

3) SW will not work over HTTP. Make sure your URL is served through HTTPS with a valid certificate.

4) Make sure your web server supports service worker. Some server like the one used in angular (ng serve) doesn't support service worker. One good option is to use http-server.

```
Install ->  npm install http-server -g
```

Run this command in your build folder ->

```
http-server -o -i 172.22.49.205 -p 8080 -S
```

5) If the URL is HTTPS with a cert and Service worker is coming green in dev tools, last chance can be what files you want to cache is not configured properly, which doesn't seem to be the case here. After loading the page, you can disconnect from network or stop the web server and check if the Chrome is still loading the page(from cache). if not, its not just your fav icon. But who cache has problem.

Comment: In the network tab, all other files are fetched from SW except the two, the assets is just api to fetch data from server, in application tab, SW is active, so which manifest files are you talking about

Comment: You have to provide screenshot of your Chrome Dev tools -> Application -> Manifest and Service worker. Without these two, its doesn't help anyone to know the state of your PWA. You have not confirmed on using HTTPS with a certificate, stopping the web server and did the the app loaded from cache(which should if SW is working as you are mentioning).

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using service worker but still can't force the browser to cache any requests to `favicon`, this question might be related: [Favicon.ico File Not Caching Despite Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67188430/favicon-ico-file-not-caching-despite-headers)