# Favicon.ico File Not Caching Despite Headers

Tags: .htaccess, favicon

I'm finding my favicon.ico file not caching. It's a static file on my server and my browser (Chrome) doesn't have caching disabled.

I have the following line in my .htaccess file:

```
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
```

Do I need to do something more?

Comment: If you take a look at the headers Chrome sends for fetching the favicon.ico (or any other icon), you'll see that the cache is always disabled in the request headers. I've tried to find the actual code causing this in the Chromium source, but didn't have any luck with that. Nor did I find any RFC or HTML spec which forces such a behaviour.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49634443/favicons-still-fetching-despite-caching-them

Answer (score 0):

It's the way browsers trying to mitigate the so called `supercookie` tracking:

https://github.com/jonasstrehle/supercookie

[https://www.cs.uic.edu/~polakis/papers/solomos-ndss21.pdf](https://www.cs.uic.edu/%7Epolakis/papers/solomos-ndss21.pdf)

https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/29801941/why-is-chrome-not-caching-the-favicon-ico-file?hl=en

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=721635

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=969033